# How to display the icons on the primary menu list in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins, menu

I am using WordPress and I have to show the search icon and add to cart icons on my primary menu.
I am not using any plugin for this.

**View source code**

```
<ul id="primary-menu-cart" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-555" class="menu-search-icon menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-555"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-554" class="menu-cart-icon menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-554"><a href="http://example.com/cart/" aria-current="page">Cart</a></li>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Css**

```
.menu-cart-icon, .menu-search-icon{position: relative;}
.menu-cart-icon:after, .menu-search-icon:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;   
height: 22px;
width: 20px;
z-index: 10;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
.menu-cart-icon:after{background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Bag.png');}
.menu-search-icon:after{background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Search.png');}
```

I am getting the icons like this. Now, How can I remove the text?

[image]

I have to display like this

[image]

Comment: color:transparent ?

Comment: Yes, color transparent is working and also I have to use some z-index for clickable